# GAE datastore data model recommendation for nested "same kind" relations

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have followed through [Bookshelf App](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/tutorial-app) tutorial (in node.js) by google and instead of books catalogue I would like to model a production part catalogue.

Where a part consists of "sub"-parts and tasks.
Every "sub"-part can have again "sub"-parts and tasks (manufacturing steps).

***Current implementation***: At the moment I have only two kinds **Parts** and **Tasks**.
A relations between the parts is managed via a property storing the unique key (parentId) of the parent part in its child part. A bigger headache I have at the moment (for example) is a price change of a highly nested sub-part would be recursively need to update all parent parts...

**Question:** What would be the recommended datastore design for such an application?

It should solve or be more efficient doing:

- If i change a "sub-sub-sub"-parts price this need to change the price of all parent parts according the chosen calculation methodology.
- Should not be limited in depth of sub-parts (I did read limits on datastore ["nested entity values"](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits) to be 20 (but probably did not understand it correctly).
- Should not be limited to 1 write per second per (part and all its sub-parts) "entity group". I've read about this limit but I am not sure whether this also applies to so called Transactions (which I think you can do on entity groups).

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution is avoid storing aggregate prices in Datastore entirely. Instead, the "price" on each part or task should only include the cost of that thing itself, but not the sub-parts.

Instead calculate the price on the fly when needed, adding up the entire tree of parts/sub-parts/tasks. Store this in memcache if you want to speed up calculation (but make sure to delete the memcache key when updating prices).

Comment: Thank you David for your suggestion. That would be possible but wouldn't that increase computational effort - if the the application is predominantly used to navigate rather then updating quantities or prices of parts, sub-part or tasks? I would like as well to understand / know whether my chosen design (storing only the parent unique id into its children parts / task) is recommended or should i move towards entitygroups (same KIND relations)?